# nodejs and angularjs single page application

Tags: node.js, angularjs, single-page-application

I want a nodejs server to host an angular single page application, using angular route module.
Does the route need to get the different views from the server every time I navigate to a different view?

Is there any way to send a bundle of htmls to the client? 
Am I missing something really basic?

Comment: You can serve the main page on `/` and use angular for the routing. You can then serve up the views as static HTML files. If you need to request data, you can do it on other routes using the `$http` provider.

Comment: That's what I was trying to ask. how to serve up views as static html files.
 if my index.html looks like this: <html> <head></head> <body> <div ng-view></div> </body> </html> I have login.html page on my server and my app.js looks like this: app.config(function($routeProvider) { $routeProvider.when("/login", { templateUrl: {}, controller: "LoginController" }) what should I write in the templateUrl?

Answer (score 0):

There are some sample applications built with Angular, you should read them before starting with something like this.

To answer your question: It depends on you.

For example the "[webmail-lite](https://github.com/afterlogic/webmail-lite)" client is a single page application (maybe not Angular but it's the same logic) and they transmit all template "views" (html snippets) as inline:

```
<script id="Mail_LayoutSidePane_Toolbar" type="text/html">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <span class="resizer_top" data-bind="event: { 'dblclick': resizeDblClick}"></span>  
    </div>
</script>
```

So you just take care of the data you want to display and create your server-side views to deliver the main index.html file and your data/RESTful/JSON-Views.

A more "clean" way of inherit templates is the use of [require.js](http://requirejs.org/).

Comment: So, if my index.html looks like this:
<html>   
<head></head> 
  <body>
   <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
I have login.html page on my server
and my app.js looks like this:
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when("/login", {
     templateUrl: {},
     controller: "LoginController"
})
what should I write in the templateUrl?

Answer (score 0):

OOPS...
ng-app was directed to the wrong module.
Therefore the route wasn't able to get the view.